# Procedure to update portable LibreOffice

Tags: updates, libreoffice, portable-apps

Having "installed" (i.e.: unpacked) LibreOfficePortable, I got a message that an update is availble.
So far, so good.

However when I clicked the button to get the update, the "normal" version of LibreOffice would have been downloaded.
I guess that feature was not adjusted for the portable version yet...

So I downloaded the newer [portable version](https://portableapps.com/apps/office/libreoffice-portable-still) manually, but was unsure how to proceed:

- Should I remove the previous directory (loosing all my customizations)
- Should I just unpack the newer version over the existing one (leaving obsolete files there, also possibly over-writing customizations, or making installed extensions unavailable)

Unfortunately there is no clear procedure available how to do it correctly.
I do not use the [PortableApps.com Updater](https://portableapps.com/platform/features#updater).

Comment: Why not download the latest portable version from [**the official LibreOffice website**](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/portable-versions/)?

Comment: Good comment: Because I did not find it when searching for the portable version.

Comment: To note, the portable versions on "the official LibreOffice website" are also simply the ones from PortableApps.com (as they clearly note on the page

Comment: @JohnSUN I don't understand: Having downloaded `LibreOfficePortablePrevious_7.5.6_MultilingualStandard.paf.exe`, executed it, and selected the existing directory, the `LibreOfficeWriterPortable.exe` is dated August 2020, and when running it, Writer reports version 7.5.3.2. Shouldn't it be 7.5.6.x instead? There is also a Writer in directory `LibreOfficePortablePrevious`, and that is dated September 2023!

Answer (score 1):

> Should I just unpack the newer version over the existing one (leaving obsolete files there, also possibly over-writing customizations, or making installed extensions unavailable)

This is the way to do it. All PortableApps.com installers are also updaters, and if the application exists in the installation location selected, it will nicely update the application and should not mess with any customizations or extensions.

---

To note, even after being fully updated on the PortableApps.com version of LibreOffice you may still get a notification (inside LibreOffice) that there is a new version available, since PortableApps.com may not have updated yet.

See [Outdated Official Portable Applications](https://portableapps.com/development/outdated) (LibreOffice's latest version is 7.6.2, while the latest PortableApps.com version for LibreOffice is still 7.6.1.)